# Performance: Geometry VS Shape

Tags: three.js

I want to create a new object with my own shape/geometry, it is a 2D rectangular frame and will be replicated something like 30000-60000 times in the scene!

What is the most efficient way to create it, using Geometry or using Shape?

How those two different classes affect memory, cpu usage and gpu usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between a shape and geometry is that geometry is a mathematical function that will be calculated each time it is generated, and then have to represent it on the screen as a bitmap. however the shape is already a bitmap that you just have to load it to memory and represent. This reflection also was made when it was decided to use the meshes and no geometries to represent elements in video games

Comment: so, looks like a shape is going to be more efficient than the geometry for this case. about the video game reflection, you mean that they realized that sprites (aka shapes) are also more efficient than geometries in some cases?

Comment: they are. You have to see it as a calculation done previously during development time, so that during runtime is not needs to be performed

Comment: It is also important to know that static memory access is one of the slowest thing out there, but if you access only once, there will be no problems. Normally static memory accesses are only made ​​at the beginning of the program to avoid continuous changes between calculations and static memory access

Comment: Great Alfonso! Gracias!